# Сохранить картинку с текстом в комп через JS

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<div id="imagee">
    <img src="image.png">
    <p>asd</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="exportimage()" >SAVE</a>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function exportimage(){

              html2canvas(document.getElementById('imagee'), {
                  onrendered: function (canvas) {
                      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                      saveAs(blob ,"image.png");
                      }, "image/png");
                      var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                      return img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                  }
              });
          }

    </script>
```

Пишу так, сохраняет как png, но без картинки, текст есть, место картинки есть но нет картинки.
Можете помочь ?

Comment: Откуда всё это запускается, случайно не с диска (`file://…`)? В таком случае загрузить картинку не получится.

Comment: Уточните, куда вы планируете сохранять? Насколько я знаю, у движка JavaScript в браузере есть ограничения на доступ к локальным ресурсам компьютера, в т.ч. к дискам. Вы можете сохранить в облако, используя облачный WebAPI, а на компьютере будет папка, в которую синхронизируются данные из облака. Это конечно то еще извращение, но рабочее.

Comment: Второй вариант, который приходит на ум, но я его не проверял, программно "кликнуть" на ссылку, которая ведет к файлу с неизвестным браузеру типом (не уверен насчет png - его браузер скорее всего просто откроет внутри себя), браузер покажет диалог сохранения файла и после нажатия соответствующей кнопки в диалоге сохранит файл.

Comment: Ну либо сохранять картинку в кеш или в LocalStorage браузера

Comment: да, запускаю с диска, то есть если заливать в сервер будет работать ?

Comment: lospejos, хочу сохранить в компьютер, он сохраняет только картинку не загружает

Comment: @Aren, вопросы такие: 1) вы запускаете этот код (html + javascript) в браузере? 2) "он сохраняет только картинку не загружает" - что именно он сохраняет?

Comment: @lospejos да, но с диска, а не на сервере.
<div id="imagee">
    <img src="image.png">
    <p>asd</p>
</div>

он оставляет место картинки пустым(не скачивает <img src="image.png">) в скаченном файле, после этого идет "asd".
я пробовал в <img src="image.png"> поставить картинку не из компа а из интернета, тоже не скачал

Comment: @lospejos смотрите в ответах, я добавил скрины, чтобы было понятнее

Answer (score 1):

В современных браузерах можно использовать атрибут `download`:

```js
function save() {
    var gh = "https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.109336634.1604/flat,550x550,075,f.u1.jpg"

    var a  = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = gh;
    a.download = 'image.png';

    a.click()
    
}
```

```html
<div id="imagee">
    <img src="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.109336634.1604/flat,550x550,075,f.u1.jpg">
    <p>ASD</p>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="save()">Save</a>
```

ps. Так же можете в `href` указывать относительный путь.

Comment: спасибо, я это знаю, но мне надо чтобы текст который ниже тоже был в сохраненной картинке